# What are some good books to learn SLR photography?

Tags: dslr, learning, books

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the first few photography books someone should read?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16/what-are-the-first-few-photography-books-someone-should-read)

I am interested in portraits and landscapes.