# Beginning photographer wants advice on how to shoot Alaskan Cruise glaciers and wildlife

Tags: lens, canon, zoom, photography-basics, wildlife

I have a Rebel T3i with Canon zoom lens EF-S 18-55 mm lens 1:3.5-5.6 IS ll and a Canon EF-S55-250 mm f/4-5.6 IS STM lens.  I would appreciate any advice on how to get clear photos and video on our Alaskan Cruise or direction on how I can use this equipment in "beginner photographer" terms.TIA

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE! Realy cool that you get the opportunity to travel on an Alaskan cruise! Currently the question you've posed is very broad. If you [take the tour](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour) you'll notice this site works best for narrow, well defined questions that show a little bit of research. Therefore I would like to ask if you can first search for similar questions and then – if you've not yet found a satisfactory answer – [edit] your question to focus on a single aspect of beginner photography with your gear.

Comment: Here are some related previous question which might help you get started in your research: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/96403/9161, https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/164/9161.
By clicking on a tag (e.g. [tag:wildlife] or [tag:photography-basics]) you can find more related questions.

Comment: To expand on Saaru's comment above: the best advice is to work on your weaknesses as a photographer; however, we can't tell you what your weaknesses are - is it your composition? Is it your technical understanding of how a camera works? Is it familiarity with your equipment so you can select the right settings quickly and accurately in the dark when wearing gloves? Almost certainly the best thing to do is to practice as much as possible before your cruise, and if you have any specific questions we can help with those. Thanks.

Comment: It appears Canon published an article about this: [Arctic Wildlife Photography Tips](https://www.canon.com.au/get-inspired/arctic-wildlife-photography-tips-young-adventuress). Subjects, composition, etc are all subjective - nobody can tell you what to shoot - but I would suggest ensuring you understand how to get [proper exposure](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/6598), understand [exposure compensation](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/4578) in case you need it, and understand what's needed to [avoid camera shake](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1733).

Comment: It goes without saying that you should try to [get your subjects in focus](https://www.canon-europe.com/pro/infobank/autofocus/).

Comment: Fifteen years ago, when I asked that question to some pros, they told me 'go and shot 10000 photos, then shoot another 10000.'  - I found that silly advise, but - surprise - it was good advice. Just go do it, often, and more often.

Comment: Wanted to add one more potentially relevant topic: [exposure modes](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/23398)

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Most Alaskan cruises are not conducted in extreme arctic winter conditions, they're done during the summer when the ambient temperatures are well above freezing and the glaciers are melting and dropping ice into the sea.

Comment: @PhilipKendall There is very little darkness in Alaska during the summer months when Alaskan cruises generally take place. At the summer solstice in Anchorage, the sun sets at around 11:45 p.m. and rises at 4:15 a.m.

Comment: My bad, I didn't know that. Perhaps it's good to include that in the question when you [edit], @busyretiredRN.