# Photographers blogs which are worth a read

Tags: learning, blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What blogs should I be following if I am learning photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/384/what-blogs-should-i-be-following-if-i-am-learning-photography)

So, for a (learning/advancing) photog, which are the best blogs and websites which he should read?

Which photog blogs are best to follow to learn more about photographie?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/384/what-blogs-should-i-be-following-if-i-am-learning-photography

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as nobody has posted anything yet I thought I'd cheekily point you in the direction of [my own blog.](http://nickminers.com) Whilst it's mostly galleries, I do other stuff, such as a few lessons on advanced photo techniques, and advice for people looking to enter competitions etc. Please let me know if you like it, and/or if you find it helpful.