# Newcomer to DSLR camera's - specifically Canon kit

Tags: canon

A friend of mine has recently acquired a Canon EOS1000D, his first digital SLR camera and would now like some good web resources to get the best out of his acquisition. Obviously, YouTube is the first port of call, but do Canon offer online tutorials for this particular model anywhere?

Thanks and kind regards to all

Comment: If he's new to photography 98.27% of what he'll want to learn is general photography info (shutter speed, depth of field, lighting, composition) that isn't specific to the 1000D.  For 1000D info, the manual is going to be the best bet.

Also, 67.4% of statistics are made up on the spot.

Answer (score 10):

Start with the camera manual, then look into these questions:

- [How to start learning photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-to-start-learning-photography)
- [What are the best online photo classes?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1928/what-are-the-best-online-photo-classes)
- [What blogs should I be following if I am learning photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/384/what-blogs-should-i-be-following-if-i-am-learning-photography)
- [What are your easiest beginner tips?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/164/what-are-your-easiest-beginner-tips)

Comment: +1 - Where else to learn but at the best Q&A site for photography!

Answer (score 0):

Canon has a website of tutorials for the Rebel series by Rick Sammon - [click here](http://www.usa.canon.com/content/Rebel_lessons/index.html).

However, I learned most of the basics by playing on my own and refusing to use automatic modes. It's digital after all, so the results of changing settings are immediately available.