# Can anyone suggest books/resources on the artistic side of photography?

Tags: composition, photography-basics, books, artistic

I am a relatively new photographer. I have no problem understanding the technical side of photography (I am an engineer by trade), but I do struggle with the more 'artistic' side of photography (composition, symmetry, choice of color/B&W...)

Can anyone suggest any reading material (either online or books) that could help improve my artistic side?

Comment: This should really be community wiki. I hate to convert it while ltn100 has so little rep, though. I may convert it later.

Comment: @jrista, I agree, great wiki topic.

Comment: Converted to community wiki.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One of the best books I can recommend is [Michael Freeman](http://www.michaelfreemanphoto.com/)'s famous book:

- [The Photographer's Eye: Composition and Design for Better Digital Photos](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0240809343)

This book is a rare gem, in that it does a pretty superb job of covering all the critical artistic topics of photography in a generally agnostic way. Michael Freeman is a talented photographer, and his communication of compositional aspects of photography is second to none. You may not learn everything about the artistic side of a specific kind of photography from this book, but you'll definitely learn the general basics that can be applied to most forms of photography.

Two other books by Michael Freeman should also find their way into your collection:

- [Michael Freeman's Perfect Exposure:
  The Professional's Guide to Capturing
  Perfect Digital Photographs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0240811712)
- [The Photographer's Mind: Creative
  Thinking for Better Digital
  Photos](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0240815173)

These three books comprise my favorites out of my entire collection, and have been the most useful (and most used) over the two or so years I've been doing photography. They do not get into the specifics of any specific field of photography, so if you are looking for detailed information information about a single field, you will have to look deeper. I generally do landscape photography, and I can offer some superb books for that field that can help you expand your artistic horizons beyond the fundamentals covered in Freeman's books. For other fields, like portraiture, architectural photography, street, etc., others can hopefully help you find what you need.

---

I do landscape, nature, and wildlife photography, so most of my books are related to that area of photography. Here are some other great books that I found that have helped me learn the artistic side of things:

- "[Developing Vision and Style: A Landscape Photography Masterclass](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1902538498)" by Joe Cornish, Charlie Wait, and David Ward — *An excellent resource of other photographers' work. One of the best ways to learn the artistic side of photography is observe the artistic photographs of other great photographers.*
- Alain Briot's "[Mastering Landscape Photography: The Luminous Landscape Essays](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1933952067)" — *Alain Briot has been a long-time contributor to the Luminous Landscape web site. This book is a more-thorough compilation of his works on that site.*
- David Noton's "[Waiting for the Light](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0715328190)" — *Another excellent book for landscape photographers, this one explains how to find and use natural light.*

When it comes to other types of photography, I don't have a whole lot to offer. I've perused some books on portrait and wedding photography, however I don't own any and couldn't offer much. Architectural photography seems to be an area that is fairly lacking in books. There do seem to be some great books from individual architectural photographers that showcase their works, and observing other photographers work is a great way to learn, but it is limited. Another field I have started to delve into is astrophotography. There do seem to be a few books and resources in that area:

- [Digital SLR Astrophotography](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521700817)
- [A Beginner's Guide to DSLR Astrophotography](http://www.astropix.com/BGDA/ORDER.HTM)
- [Long Exposure Astrophotography](http://www.naturescapes.net/docs/index.php/category-technical/145-long-exposure-astrophotography)
- [Catching the Light](http://www.astropix.com/)

---

Most of the books I have learned from are for landscape and wildlife/bird photography, so I am not certain how useful they will be for you. I think the compositional concepts are very sound, and apply to more than just nature photography, however.

- [The Photographers Eye: Composition and Design for Better Digital Photos](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0240809343)

  - Fantastic book on composition from a general perspective...definitely a must have if you need to learn more about composition
- [Waiting for the Light](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0715328190)

  - Excellent book for landscape photographers, has some good tips on composition, but mostly about natural lighting, how and when to find it, etc.
- [Mastering Landscape Photography: The Luminous Landscape Essays](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1933952067)

  - Another excellent book that has some great examples of composition with visual examples
- [100 Ways to Take Better Nature and Wildlife Photographs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0715331493)

  - Mostly wildlife, however the compositional tips are superb
- [Developing Vision and Style](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1902538498)

  - Not so much a book explicitly about composition, however it has a ton of example nature & landscape photographs from visionary photographers that make excellent material to review and learn from...some truly fantastic stuff. All photographs, their location, and the gear used to capture them is detailed in the back of the book. Each set of photographs from each interviewed photographer includes their sense of vision and style, which can be helpful.
- [Working the Light: A Photography Masterclass](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1902538463)

  - Good examples of quality composition, again, all landscape

Comment: Thanks jrista. I've seen a couple of mentions of _The Photographer's Eye_ now, so I think I'll put an order in for that :)

Answer (score 6):

These are some quite advanced texts covering the artistic and cultural side of photography:

- Batchen, G (2000) Over Exposed. London: The New Press
- Berger, J. (1972). Ways of seeing. London: Pelican
- Brittain, D. (ed.) (1999) Creative Camera: 30 Years of Writing. Manchester: MUP
- Burgin, V (1982) Thinking Photography. Macmillan Press (see Benjamin ‘The Author as Producer’.)
- Burke, S. (1998). The Death and return of the Author – Criticsim and Subjectivity in Barthes, Foucault and Derrida. Edinburgh: EUP
- Cotton, C (2004) The Photograph as Contemporary Art. London Thames & Husdon
- Evans, J ed. (1997) The Camerawork Essays. Rivers Oram Press
- Evans, Jessica & Hall, Stuart (1999) Visual culture: the reader. London. Sage
- Frizot, Michael (1998). A New History of Photography. Konemann
- Lister, M. (ed.) (2003) The Photographic Image in Digital Culture. London: Routledge
- Mitchell, W.J. (1992) The Reconfigured Eye: Visual Truth in the Post-Photographic Era Cambridge, M.A MIT
- Mirzoeff, Nicholas. (1999) An introduction to Visual Culture. Routledge
- Newhall, B (1982) The History of Photography. New York Secker & Warburg
- Newhall, B. (1980) Essays & Images. New York Secker & Warburg (See Strand essay 1917)
- Payne, M. (ed). (1996). Cultural and Critical Theory. Oxford: Blackwell.
- Ritchen, F. (1999) In Our Own Image: The Coming Revolution in Photography. New York: Aperture
- Squires, C ed. (1990) The Critical Image. Seattle Bay Press
- Trachtenberg, A. (1980) Classic Essays on Photography New Haven, Conn. Leete’s Island
- Traub, C. (ed) (2006) The Education of a Photographer New York: Allworth Press

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link to a page with many links to online articles on image composition.

http://photoinf.com/

Answer (score 4):

Eventually instruction-oriented books won't be as useful to you, and you'll need to start looking at (and thinking about) photography directly.  What you should pick when you get to that point will depend on your taste, but if you have even an inkling of interest in street photography or photojournalism, there are worse places to start than this:

[Magnum Magnum](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0500543666) (hardcover - [paperback here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0500288305))

400 photographs from the [Magnum](http://magnumphotos.com) archives: Henri Cartier-Bresson, Martin Parr, Alec Soth, and many others.

If you can find it (and want to splurge a bit), the original giant hardcover edition (more than 30x45cm) is amazing. Larger is definitely better for these images.

Answer (score 4):

A few book recommendations:

- [Photography and the Art of Seeing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1552636143) by Freeman Patterson
- [Tao of Photography: Seeing Beyond Seeing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1580081940) by Philippe Gross
- [Within the Frame: the Journey of Photographic Vision](http://ttp://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321605020?ie=UTF8&tag=pp-gen-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=0321605020) by David duChemin

Answer (score 4):

You may also want to try the "5 Photo Composition Hints" series of web articles from ShotAddict.com:

1. [The First Element - Texture](http://www.shotaddict.com/tips/article_5+Photo+Composition+Hints.+The+First+Element+-+Texture.html)
2. [The Second Element - Color](http://www.shotaddict.com/tips/article_5+Photo+Composition+Hints.+The+Second+Element+-+Color.html)
3. [The Third Element - Subject](http://www.shotaddict.com/tips/article_5+Photo+Composition+Hints.+The+Third+Element+-++Subject.html)
4. [The Fourth Element - Space](http://www.shotaddict.com/tips/article_5+Photo+Composition+Hints.+The+Fourth+Element+-+Space.html)
5. [The Fifth Element - Light](http://www.shotaddict.com/tips/article_5+Photo+Composition+Hints.+The+Fifth+Element+-+Light.html)

Comment: +1 A good series there. (links to the other 4 sections are at the bottom of the page)

Comment: Not working any longer. Does anyone know if these links have been changed?

Comment: yep not working now. any alternative links?

Answer (score 3):

"The Photographer's Eye: Composition and Design for Better Digital Photos" by Michael Freeman is a pretty good book : [http://www.amazon.com/Photographers-Eye-Composition-Design-Digital/dp/0240809343](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0240809343)

Answer (score 3):

I am a big fan of Freeman Patterson's books.  I started with [Photography for the Joy of it](http://www.amazon.ca/Photography-Joy-Introductory-Workshop-Digital/dp/155263793X/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1289592716&sr=1-3) and then "Photography and the Art of Seeing" already linked to by ahockley.  Then I added others of his:

- [Photographing the World Around You](http://www.amazon.ca/Photographing-World-Around-You-Freeman/dp/1552636127/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1289592716&sr=1-2) by Freeman Patterson
- [Photography of Natural Things](http://www.amazon.ca/Photography-Natural-Things-Environment-Workshop/dp/1552635988/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1289592716&sr=1-5) by Freeman Patterson

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any specific book recommendation (I don't tend to read books a lot, as it seems), but I would suggest not getting too focused on "photographic composition", but rather widen the field into "image composition". Composition is a field that has been of interest for as long as man has created images, so there is a lot to learn from the painters that have been around for so much longer than photography.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest David Ward's ["Landscape Beyond: Insights and Inspirations for Photographers"](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Landscape-Beyond-Insights-Inspirations-Photographers/dp/190253851X) and Freeman Patterson's ["Photography and the Art of Seeing: A Visual Perception Workshop for Film and Digital Photography"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1552636143). These are not just composition books, but rather talking about the process of getting from taker to maker (David Ward's quote).

Answer (score 1):

Kodak has a great book that I found at my library.

- [Mastering Composition and Light](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0867062118)

Answer (score 1):

One of the best book for begginers, but not only. This is no joke:
[US-Navy-Course-NAVEDTRA-14209-Photography-Basic](http://www.scribd.com/doc/7835975/US-Navy-Course-NAVEDTRA-14209-Photography-Basic)

Simple, but very usable tips for composition, portratits and just what you should know about photography, if you are enthusiast or want do better photos.

Comment: I've read the training manual.  It is rather outdated in terms of the technology discussed, but gives a very good look at how to get your images "right".

Comment: Of course outdated, but rules not changed ;) I saw many qestions here which are the answers in this book. Composition, portrait etc. And it just look outdated, I not see any obsolescence issues here. Only what is outdated, that digital imaging is not discussed, but this is for post processing only not shoting.

Answer (score 1):

Your natural inclination as an engineer is to go for a book. I teach my students to use their loves and fears to explore meaningful content in their work.

As reason and science defines elegant engineering solutions - motivation tempered by emotion will help you focus your attention on images which go beyond the mechanical.

You need life not books. Your best images may be seconds away if you can find the inspiration to expand your life.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to suggest buying photo art/coffee table books -- collections of great photographs. To me exposure to good photography helps to inspire your own, as long as you don't succumb to just imitating. You would expect the Beatles to have listened to The Band, and Michelangelo was probably familiar with the work of Leonardo da Vinci.

Which books to purchase (or online galleries to review) really depends on what kind of photography you are into, but if you don't know of any famous photographers you could try google/wikipedia searches like "contemporary photographers" or "american west photographers" and once you get some names start looking up their work.

Or you could start looking at the work of Ralph Gibson, Edward Weston, Ansel Adams (who was kind of a geek, liked to understand processes, why things worked the way they did), Henri Cartier-Bresson, Richard Avedon, Diane Arbus, Annie Leibovitz, or Gregory Crewdson.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people have suggested books, and articles, but I'd like to add (internet) photography forums, or even just photography sections on other forums. If you find one which has users with portfolios you like, and the people who post there don't seem *too* up themselves, then you really lose nothing by joining and posting.

These create a really great was for you to get live constructive criticism, and help you develop your own style and sense of photography, eventually leading to learning how to critique yourself, and when to see if the critique is objective or subjective as you get better and better.

Answer (score 0):

**Best digested by a photographer that already has some experience**

*Photographer's Eye* and *Photographers Mind* by Michael Freeman are excellent. *Photographic Composition* and *Perception and Imaging* by Richard Zakia are great, too.

**For a less experienced photographers**

*National Geographic Photography Field Guide: Secrets to Making Great Pictures* is a great starting point.