# Which famous photographers used mostly one lens throughout their careers?

Tags: lens, focal-length, history

Which famous or outstanding photographers did use mostly only one focal length throughout their career and what focal length did they use? For medium and large format photography, please indicate a 35mm “equivalent”.

For example, Cartier-Bresson used 50 mm lens [almost exclusively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Cartier-Bresson#Technique).

Comment: To moderators: Please make it a community wiki.

Comment: This is kind of a 'neat' thing to talk about, but its not really appropriate within the SE format.  CW isn't really something you start out asking for, its something mainly for answers, and something you kinda of 'end up with' http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/ .

Comment: @rfusca This question is not for fun. It is about the history of _photography_. It is not subjective or argumentative, it asks for _facts_ and _references_. And it is not a trivial question which can be solved in few seconds of googling. The question doesn't allow a single answer, every answer is valuable. The intent of the question is to share the burden of research, hence I assume that CW is applicable to the Q (it needs true community collaboration, and every contribution is equal), not to the As. On closing: this Q asks for pure facts and references, not for opinions or arguments.

Comment: Its a great history lesson, I agree - I just don't think it fits in the format of a Q&A.  Unless we see somebody who is going to go research every photographer.  The site format promotes questions that are a solution to a problem and have an actual answer - the blog entry is indicative that CW is not to be used as a crutch for questions outside the format.  Either the question is strong enough to stand without CW or not at all to me.  I'm not suggesting its not valuable information, just maybe not appropriate for the site format.

Comment: @rfusca OK, the probem at hand is that I'd like to study the works of such photographers, but lack references to start with. It's impossible to research each and every photographer, but individual knowledge may accumulate over time. And every small contribution counts. I think this questions fits in the format of Q&A much better, than, for instance, http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/7520/1558 http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/4804/1558 http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2296/1558

Comment: I especially agree on the first one.  I think the issue of mine is kind of confirmed by the fact that there's only been a single answer.

Comment: These kinds of "topics" really don't bring much beneficial content to this forum, as such things are really discussions, not Q&A. We had a few topics like this early on, but that was before the official StackExchange chat system was brought out of beta and publicly online. I'm going to close this, and recommend that if you wish to **discuss** any topics, you should hop into our chat room where free-flowing discussion is much easier and more effective. All chats are logged and kept, and useful comments can be starred, so conversations will not be lost.

Comment: @jrista I don't want to _discuss_. I want facts. Chat might be good for immediate answers, but it is not persistent. Unlike "Who is your favourite photographer?" and "Which photographer you find inspirational?", this question is inlikely to get immediate answers, but may accumulate them over time. Could have if it were not closed. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Helmut Newton used a medium-format Rollieflex with an 80mm f/2.8 lens for most of his career.