# What are the best books on posing?

Tags: books, posing, models

I'm interested in reading some good, informative books on posing and interacting with people for photography. Which are the best ones?

Comment: Hrm, I can't seem to make this Community Wiki. It should be, IMO.

Comment: See also [Books/resources on the artistic side of photography?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4804/books-resources-on-the-artistic-side-of-photography) and [What are the first few photography books someone should read?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16/what-are-the-first-few-photography-books-someone-should-read). I'm looking for ones specifically for dealing with models, ideally not on those lists.

Comment: Picture Perfect Posing by Roberto Valenzuela seems to be highly recommended. Have not red it yet, but will, soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not limited to books, but consider videos as well, than you will find an exceptional presentation of this matter that in Bambi Cantrell's 3-day workshop in [creativeLIVE](http://www.creativelive.com/courses/posing-and-lighting-bambi-cantrell).

She covers there, through live shooting of models, the basics and advanced techniques of posing your model and yourself in various situation, to get a message transferred. In addition she teaches how to effectively communicate with the model, mainly without *touchig* her/him.

Comment: I'm definitely interested in non-book resources, though that doesn't help me get free Amazon shipping. ;-)

Comment: FWIW, she has [three books](http://www.amazon.ca/s?_encoding=UTF8&search-alias=books-ca&field-author=Bambi%20Cantrell) that look interesting.

Comment: But you *do* get free shipping, don't you? ;-)