# Which is a good photography book?

Tags: digital, books

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the first few photography books someone should read?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16/what-are-the-first-few-photography-books-someone-should-read)

I have to gift a friend a photography book. And I have no knowledge about photography. which book would you suggest that can b gifted?

Comment: The term "photography book" covers a lot of territory. Do you want a how-to book (and would it be general or for a particular type of photography) or something inspirational (and again, is there a preferred genre or artist that would strike the recipient)?

Comment: Either a general how-to book.. or something with a variety of photographs by renowned photographers... i got some links on books by national geographic photographers but i donno how good they would be..

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [flatbooks.com](http://www.flatbooks.com). You'll be able to find a number of high quality books on a variety of photography subjects. They are written by a number of authors who know what they are doing in their subjects.

One possible stumbling point for this answer is that the books at [flatbooks.com](http://www.flatbooks.com) are all ebooks.

As far as which one to buy I think that making a suggestion would be very difficult without knowing your friend, but I would suggest buying a book that fits the style of photographs they take, assuming you've seen some of the photos they've taken.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of great photography books and sadly much more horrible ones.

You should think about the recipient. If he likes a certain style of photography, you can find something specifically on Architectural, Panorama, etc. I [review plenty of such Photography books here](http://www.neocamera.com/articles/book).

Beautiful photography books are very appreciated by photographers too and I own dozens myself. I am partial to National Geographic and find their picture books excellently priced. [This 504 page book](http://shop.nationalgeographic.com/ngs/product/books/photography/wide-angle) is one of my favorites. Browse [around here](http://shop.nationalgeographic.com/ngs/category/books/photography) for other books filled with amazing photography.

Answer (score 0):

That entirely depends on how advanced your friend is. If he owns a DSLR, shoots thousands of photos and posts them online, if you would describe him as a semi-pro or very advanced amateur, I would not buy him a book about photography theory, techniques or worse, basics. He will not benefit much from it.

I actually made the same mistake a few years ago and I bought my friend a 'photography' book. But I doubt he's read it once. It is easier to find answers to your questions online. And there are plenty of great resources, like [Adorama Learning Center](http://www.adorama.com/alc/), with videos to watch - easier than reading a book.

So for an advanced amateur **I would try and find a book about [famous photographers](http://improvephotography.com/1946/famous-photographers/)**, maybe an album with their photos.

I will not duplicate what other people said already - if you decide to get a photography book the other answers are great.