# Good resource to learn taking professional pictures

Tags: effect

I hope you can help me find the kind of resource I need. I want to learn to use my own camera, Its Nikon P510, I have the user guide and of course it teaches how to use it.  But what I want to learn is how to make those kind of pictures like:

1. Night rays
2. A person looks standing, but the background seems moving

I wonder if there is any website that tells me do this, change this parameter for this effect, change this other parameter for that effect

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Welcome to the site. I have a few recommendations to improve this question. First off, I would separate this into two questions - 1.How do take a photo of night rays similar to this example 2.How to take a photo of a person standing with background moving similar to this example. Then, please define what you mean by "professional pictures" in each question. Finally, make sure to include a link to an example of each effect as your wording can mean multiple different things such as "night rays".

Comment: I would recommend picking up Scott Kelby's book "The Digital Photography Book", it outlines answers to both of your questions and more, in a very easy to understand format. Other recommendations for books can be found here - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16/what-are-the-first-few-photography-books-someone-should-read

Comment: why so unfriendly in closing questions? really? not very friendly.

Comment: I don't know why you think anyone was unfriendly. I gave you lots of tips and recommendations to improve your question so it does get answered here. I also gave you what I think is the best answer which is to buy the book I recommended. See our FAQ on how to ask questions here for more info: http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keywords that you are probably looking for are: Long exposure photography, tripod photography, panning, exposure.

[Here](http://www.learnoutdoorphotography.com/2011/06/photographing-waterfalls.html), [here](http://photo.tutsplus.com/articles/shooting-articles/the-best-way-to-learn-about-long-exposure-photography/) and [here](http://digital-photography-school.com/mastering-panning-to-photograph-moving-subjects)  I have found some tutorials/information about this subject.

To answer your questions in short:

1: You will have to set you camera to 'manual' (M) or 'shutter mode' (S or Tv) and have to select quite a long exposure (in seconds). You have to use a sturdy floor (could be achieved by using a tripod). By using the self timer of the camera you prevent moving the camera and adding camera shake.

2: You have to find a subject (a person for example) that stands still, another object (a train for example) has to move in the background. A moderately long  shutter speed is needed and you could consider using a tripod.

This type of photography (just like any other type of photography) requires 'trial and error', then you will fully understand and master it.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this site is actually a good resource for finding the information you are looking for.  If you want to know about how to do a particular style of photo, you can simply ask about that style and we should be able to provide you with the help you need. If you are able to post a sample of the kind of look you are trying to achieve we can do an even better job of making sure that we know what you are looking for.